# is the possible to get the columns name in Mysql?

Tags: mysql

I am new to SQL, and I have a problem in my practice program,

assume I have a table below:

```
----------------------------------------
job_Name  | member1 | member2 | member3 | ...The number of members is unknown 
-----------------------------------------
  ABC     |  10     |    20   |  null   | ...The value is the price which paid 
-----------------------------------------
  bcd     |  null   |    20   |  null   | ...to the member. that mean member1 
-----------------------------------------
  asd     |  null   |    20   |  10     | ...and member2 finish this job 
-----------------------------------------
  qwe     |  10     |    20   |  10     | ...togeter
```

What I want to get below:

```
--------------------------------------
job_Name | members                   | 
--------------------------------------
  ABC     |  member1,member2         | 
--------------------------------------
  bcd     |  member2                 | 
--------------------------------------
  asd     |  member2,member3         |   
--------------------------------------
  qwe     |  member1,member2,member3 |
```

This is easy to get on excel with Visual Basic

In Mysql, I have no idea about that.

Comment: It is possible, but I would not do this in mysql. Search for unpivot, then apply group_concat on top of it, if you really insist.

Comment: This kind of problem is symptomatic of poor design. Consider revising your schema.

Comment: A database engine such as MySQL has stricter constraints for the data, compared to a spreadsheet. The latter allows you to type pretty much anything, while a database has a rigid structure that prevents you from enteing bad data. Having said that, what you need is a "dynamic PIVOT/UNPIVOT" operation, that is not available on databases.